# convert curly quotes to straight quotes when user queries solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solrconfig

I am new to solr and trying to figure out how do I convert curly quotes to straight quotes when a user queries. 
Currently I am doing it using the method and it works perfectly fine.

```
//converts raw user query string with curly quotes to straight quotes
private static String querystrPreprocessor(String query, SolrParams params) 
{
query = SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.convertUnicodeQuotes(query, params);
return query;
}
```

But I want to do it in solrconfig.xml
I have added solr.MappingCharFilterFactory to solrConfig.xml

```
<queryParser name="synonym_edismax" class="solr.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin">
  <lst name="charFilter">
     <str name="class">solr.MappingCharFilterFactory</str>
     <str name="mapping">mapping-FoldToASCII.txt</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="tokenizer">
     <str name="class">solr.PatternTokenizerFactory</str>
     <str name="pattern"><![CDATA[(?:\s|\")+]]></str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="filter">
     <str name="class">solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory</str>
  </lst>
</queryParser>
```

Is it the right way to do it? 
Also, how do I use it in the code? Do I need to write java code for it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say do it in code?

Comment: I mean to say do I need to write a java code that would use the MappingCharFilterFactory or just adding the charFilter in solrconfig.xml will do the work and I can get rid of the java method I have?

Comment: You don't need any java method. If you're indexing regularly through `/update` or DIH, you just need to ensure that your field is defined in `schema.xml` and it has this filter factory in the index analyzer stage.

Comment: @BinoyDalal - I am overriding createParser() and parseConfig() methods for my synonym logic. I am reading the solrconfig.xml file in parseConfig() for synonym thing.

Comment: Does this synonym logic have anything to do with the quotes?

Comment: No it does not.  But "charFilter" is part of <queryParser> </queryParser> in xml and I override createParser() and parseConfig() methods so I was worried if I do not write the java code for solr.MappingCharFilterFactory would it work or not. MappingCharFilterFactory has parseString() method https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/MappingCharFilterFactory.java